# What does clearing "Active Login" does in Firefox

Tags: firefox

I don't understand the use of using "Active Login" option. Can anybody help?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Active Logins: If you have logged in to a website that uses HTTP authentication since you most recently opened Firefox, that site is considered "active". Clearing this logs you out of those sites.

[Source](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/remove-recent-browsing-search-and-download-history#w_what-things-are-included-in-my-history)

Comment: I'm not sure that is correct. Session data on sites like Facebook are stored in cookies, which look like any other cookie to the browser. Active logins probably refers to [HTTP authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

Comment: @Bob, yes, that's a good point. Answer updated.